Nuxt i18n: Failed to resolve import “locales/en.json” (Does the file exist?)
Description:
I’m facing an issue while setting up the @nuxtjs/i18n module in my Nuxt 3 project. When I run the application, I get the following error:
Failed to resolve import "../i18n/locales/en.json" from ".nuxt/i18n.options.mjs". Does the file exist?
Project Structure:
The JSON files are located in the locales folder, at the root of the project.
Code:
nuxt.config.ts file :
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: "2024-11-01",
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  css: ["~/assets/css/main.css"],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/i18n",
    "@nuxt/icon",
    "@vueuse/motion/nuxt",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts",
  ],
  i18n: {
    lazy: true,
    langDir: "locales/",
    strategy: "prefix_and_default",
    locales: [
      { code: "en", name: "English", iso: "en-US", file: "en.json" },
      { code: "fr", name: "Français", iso: "fr-FR", file: "fr.json" },
    ],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
  googleFonts: {
    families: {
      Inter: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900],
    },
    display: "swap",
  },
});

Here’s the content of my en.json file for testing purposes:
{
  "welcome": "Welcome"
}

Steps I’ve already tried:

Verified the project structure and file paths.
Added a trailing / to the langDir in the configuration.

Hope someone can unlock this.
Thank you for your time.

Ok I just added ../ before the path to locales folder... Not written in the doc!

It's not really a Nuxt documentation issue, more of the structure of your project hence why it's not in the docs.
